# Is there any way to solved DOMPDF 2 column issue

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I used **DOMPDF** for my laravel project, but there is one issue when I used two-column in my HTML file, and the first column has large data as compared to column two, so when data come on the next page, column two start from the next page.
I am trying in different ways, but still, second column data not stick with column 1 in the first page, it comes on the second page.

Please help is there any way in **DOMPDF** to solved this issue.

Comment: set out width in percentages with `style="table-layout:fixed;"` it should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply for table format and set alignment of td like align top and i think your problem has been resolved.

Comment: I already did this, but it not work, have you checked with dompdf.
Because I also used div under second column that also not working.

Comment: Please check
http://gatewayofsuccess.com/pdf/pdf.txt 
http://gatewayofsuccess.com/pdf/dompdf.pdf 
http://gatewayofsuccess.com/pdf/pdf.php